# Is it possible to obtain the 5-tuple for a process TCP connection?

Tags: android, ip

I have the UID of a process that I whant to monitor and to do that I need to get hold of the 5-tuple, (source IP address, destination IP address, source port number, destination port number and the protocol in use) programmatically and without root access.

Is this even possible? (And if yes, how?)

Thank you in advance

//Q

Comment: "Is this even possible?" -- I certainly hope not, as that would be a massive privacy hole.

Comment: @CommonsWare Figured it out. /proc/net/tcp holds the information I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Android is Linux based there are four files in /proc/net/. One for TCP, TCP6, UDP and UDP6 respectively holding the information for all connections and their corresponding process id. To obtain this information I first got a list of all installed apps via

```
ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager)
this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

Then it's simply  a matter of matching the process name agains the process you are interested in to get the proc id and parsing the tcp file to match connection against process id.